# Getting an object recognized after closing an R function

Tags: r, function

Suppose I write a simple function called `TT` and close it. **How can I retrieve/call one of the elements within this function outside the function?**

**Here is an R code** where I try to call `x` outside the function?

```
TT <- function(){

      x <- rnorm(7)
      y <- rnorm(5)

   cat(x) ## what to use instead of "cat" to make "x" or "y" recognizable       
           # outside the function if "x" or "y" were called outside the function?
   }

TT()

      x + 4   ## Currently not recognized?
```

Comment: You need to return a value/object instead of printing it. Replace `cat(x)` with `list(x=x, y=y)` maybe? Then you can do `TT()$x + 4` for instance.

Comment: You could read up on environments and perhaps the `<<-` operator.

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks. But this requires that the function runs again, Is there a way to find out what what was/were x when function ran first?

Comment: @parvinkarimi - save the results then - `tmp <- TT()` then `tmp$x + 4`

Comment: @parvinkarimi - if you need to use `<<-` i'd argue you're not doing it right.

Comment: @parvinkarimi - the `list` I suggested returns both vectors together. You will have `tmp$x` and `tmp$y` using my above example.

Comment: Read through the SO R Documentation section for scoping http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/3138/scope-of-variables#t=201702200008566131213

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: you don't. R functions are not (generally) meant to have side-effects that create objects in your global workspace. So change your `TT` function to return an object instead, like:

```
set.seed(1)
TT <- function() {
  x <- rnorm(7)
  y <- rnorm(5)
  list(x=x, y=y)
}
TT()
#$x
#[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078 -0.8204684  #0.4874291
#
#$y
#[1]  0.7383247  0.5757814 -0.3053884  1.5117812  0.3898432
```

Then you can directly call the results of this function in another operation like:

```
set.seed(1)
TT()$x + 4
#[1] 3.373546 4.183643 3.164371 5.595281 4.329508 3.179532 4.487429
```

Or save the results to an intermediary object if you don't want to keep re-calculating the result:

```
set.seed(1)
tmp <- TT()
tmp$x + 4
#[1] 3.373546 4.183643 3.164371 5.595281 4.329508 3.179532 4.487429
```